# How validate some fields in posted form in HandlerInterceptorAdapter

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I'm writing CaptchaInterceptor based on HandlerInterceptorAdapter. In preHandle method i must check capcha value. How from this method add errors messages and send user back to form with not valid cactha value and do not lost user inputed data?

```
public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object o) throws Exception {
/*  Validate */
String kaptchaExpected = (String)request.getSession().getAttribute(com.google.code.kaptcha.Constants.KAPTCHA_SESSION_KEY);
String kaptchaReceived = request.getParameter("j_kaptcha");
    if (!StringUtils.endsWithIgnoreCase(kaptchaReceived,kaptchaExpected))
    {
     // add errorMessage
     // reset request values?
     response.sendRedirect(request.getHeader("Referer"));

    return false;
    }
return true;
}
```

Or add errors and send request to handler. In BindingResult object controller will somehow find errors and send all data back.

Answer (score 0):

Out of the box you'll need to add the error message onto the session, then inside of your preHandle or postHandle method of the next request you will need to check the session to see if error messages exist.

```
public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, 
                       Object handler, ModelAndView modelAndView) {
    //Best to put them in some sort of iterable, so your UI can iterate over them
    Object errorMessages = 
        request.getSession().getAttribute(ERROR_MESSAGES_CONSTANT);

    modelAndView.addObject("errorMessages", errorMessages);
}
```

Inside of your view you will need to handle the error messages (if they exist).

Once that is done you will want to clear it from the session (so they don't see the same message on each and every page).

```
public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
                       Object handler, ModelAndView modelAndView) {

  request.getSession().setAttribute(ERROR_MESSAGES_CONSTANT, null);
}
```